# How do you find the I2C address of the Pi?

Tags: i2c

My friend and I have been working on finding the I2C address of the Raspberry Pi, but have had no luck. We're planing on having the Raspberry pi sending data to a RoboRIO, which needs to have an address to connect to.

Anyone know it or know how to find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The I2C bus is master only. You cannot connect it as a slave, hence it does not have an address to find. The relationship between a master and a slave device is that the master may read from or write to the slave but not vice versa (which is why an address for the master is not meaningful).

Comment: Alright, Is it possible to bypass the parameter of a constructor like this? 

http://first.wpi.edu/FRC/roborio/stable/docs/java/classedu_1_1wpi_1_1first_1_1wpilibj_1_1I2C.html

The pi will be the only device on this I2C bus so If I could read in all incomming data that would work too.

Comment: Any parameter which asks you for an I2C address is asking for a slave device; that's the nature of the protocol.  Since the pi's bus can *only* be a master, you cannot use the pi for that purpose.